L2TP Debian12 server and Vodafone Power Station SGH3000 client
i have a debian12 server running xl2tpd and strongswan as vpn server and a vodafone router on the remote site configurared as l2tp client.
i'm not interested on routing all internet traffic but only to reach all devices in the two lans from both sites.
if i disable encryption on vodafone router everything is working correctly, connecting directly to port 1701 xl2tpd.
if i enable it, it's not working, after some seconds i get:
deleting half open IKE_SA with <remote_client_public_ip> after timeout

port 500 are open and natted on both sides.
below my config:
/etc/ipsec.conf
config setup
    charondebug="ikev2 2, ike 2, knl 2, cfg 2"
conn %default
    dpdtimeout=30
    dpdaction=restart
conn my_vpn
    keyexchange=ikev1
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp1536
    esp=aes128-sha1-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp1536
    left=%any
    right=%any
    rightauth=psk
    fragmentation=yes
    auto=add

/etc/ipsec.secrets
%any : PSK "<my_preshared_key>"

full log:
systemd[1]: Started strongswan-starter.service - strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using ipsec.conf.
systemd[1]: Starting xl2tpd.service - LSB: layer 2 tunelling protocol daemon...
ipsec[229133]: Starting strongSwan 5.9.8 IPsec [starter]...
charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.8, Linux 6.1.0-16-amd64, x86_64)
xl2tpd[229142]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.
xl2tpd[229142]: Using l2tp kernel support.
xl2tpd[229135]: Starting xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
charon: 00[CFG] PKCS11 module '<name>' lacks library path
systemd[1]: Started xl2tpd.service - LSB: layer 2 tunelling protocol daemon.
charon: 00[PTS] TPM 2.0 - could not load "libtss2-tcti-tabrmd.so.0"
charon: 00[LIB] plugin 'tpm': failed to load - tpm_plugin_create returned NULL
xl2tpd[229143]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.18 started on wallygbr.404.mn PID:229143
xl2tpd[229143]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
xl2tpd[229143]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
xl2tpd[229143]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
xl2tpd[229143]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006-2016
xl2tpd[229143]: Listening on IP address <local_server_ip>, port 1701
charon: 00[LIB] providers loaded by OpenSSL: legacy default
charon: 00[NET] using forecast interface enp0s3
charon: 00[CFG] joining forecast multicast groups: 224.0.0.1,224.0.0.22,224.0.0.251,224.0.0.252,239.255.255.250
charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'
charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'
charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'
charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'
charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any
charon: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
charon: 00[CFG] HA config misses local/remote address
charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon test-vectors ldap pkcs11 aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt pkcs8 af-alg fips-prf gmp curve25519 agent chapoly xcbc cmac hmac kdf ctr ccm gcm drbg curl attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark forecast farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-aka eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam tnc-tnccs dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity counters
charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0
charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
ipsec[229133]: charon (229141) started after 40 ms
charon: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'my_vpn'
charon: 05[CFG] added configuration 'my_vpn'

charon: 08[NET] received packet: from <remote_client_public_ip>[500] to <local_server_ip>[500] (592 bytes)
charon: 08[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V V ]
charon: 08[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: 4f:53:57:73:78:6c:6a:46:40:54:53:59
charon: 08[IKE] received DPD vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03 vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-00 vendor ID
charon: 08[IKE] <remote_client_public_ip> is initiating a Main Mode IKE_SA
charon: 08[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048
charon: 08[ENC] generating ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V ]
charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from <local_server_ip>[500] to <remote_client_public_ip>[500] (136 bytes)
charon: 10[NET] received packet: from <remote_client_public_ip>[500] to <local_server_ip>[500] (356 bytes)
charon: 10[ENC] parsed ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
charon: 10[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
charon: 10[ENC] generating ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from <local_server_ip>[500] to <remote_client_public_ip>[500] (372 bytes)
charon: 09[IKE] sending keep alive to <remote_client_public_ip>[500]
charon: 10[JOB] deleting half open IKE_SA with <remote_client_public_ip> after timeout


poste edited for new problem

"On both sides" ? Really ? It looks from your logs that even IKE cannot establish SA. Furthermore, when both VPN server and client are behind NAT - you should really avoid this, man, Setup a VPN server on a device that is serving your NAT.

yes on both sides, without ipsec from 192.168.10.x i reach 192.168.20.x and viceversa. l2tp server (debian) is natted but not client (vodafone station)

Then accept the fate.
